# Setting up crossdomain jsonp callback function for ajax

Tags: ajax

```
      $('#image_upload_form input').change(function() {

        if ( $(this).val() == '') return false;



        $('#image_upload_form').ajaxSubmit({
            url: "http://www.test.com/offers/upload_image?callback=?",
           type: "POST",
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           data: {},
            jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',

            success: function ( data ) { })     
            }   //success
            });      //submit

        //place1    var mycallback=function(data) { console.log(data);}

    });

       //place2     
       var mycallback=function(data) { console.log(data);}
```

My first question is where do I put that jsonpCallback function? place1 or place2 or it doesn't matter

From the Server side I make sure the output response would be

```
       mycallback({.....});
```

I put a break point near the mycallback function  but it doesn't seem to fire up.

Comment: Note that JSONP does not support POST.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.
jQuery creates callback automatically;
 you can just write

```
$.getJSON("http://www.test.com/offers/upload_image?callback=?", function(...) { ... })
```

Comment: Where would you put this line?   Do I still need that ajaxSubmit function?

Comment: I think I still need the ajaxSubmit because it's form post to send an image file to server.

Comment: @jasonwhite: You cannot do that with JSONP.